# Getting file path or video on iOS / Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, video

I'm trying to capture video on an iOS (Cordova) app. I can get a file name, (a string of characters ending ".MOV") but can't see how to turn this into a fileURI (beginning "file:///"). Can anyone make any suggestions?

The video capture code is:

```
<div class="add-video btn">
    <label for="video-input"><img src="css/img/video-w20.png"></label>
    <input id="video-input" type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcorder"> 
</div>
```

there's an onChange function attached to '#video-input', and I a getting the file name in there by:

```
var VideoInput=$("#video-input")[0];
var file = VideoInput.files[0];
```

(the file name appears as file.name)

Comment: In a web browser, JavaScript can never directly access the user's file system. That means JavaScript can't turn the selected file in a `file://` path. However, I'm not sure if this is different for cordova.

Comment: The thing is that, in Cordova, navigator.camera.getPicture works with a URI for where the photo goes, which begins file:// I am trying to modify an app that used to take photos, to add videos, and am keen (in the interests of maintainability) for the pathway for handling videos to be as close as possible to that for photos -- so am looking for a way to get the URI as the code catching the video is different from that catching the photo.